# Very long delay for registering a new user with SuperLogin/Couchdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, couchdb, delay

[edit: User registration with SuperLogin implies the creation of a per-user database. After investigation it finally looks like the 30-second delay is coming from CouchDB itself and alone, when creating a new database. I now have to understand why CouchDB takes so long to do this...]

I am facing a 30-second delay when registering a new user through SuperLogin in a CouchDB database. Sometimes it's even longer, causing a timeout error in the server.

However, everything runs on the same local machine, Fauxton is usually pretty fast, as well as the data synchronization I am doing between this CouchDB database and a PouchDB app.

Would you have any idea about how to fix this? Or at least how to get more logs about what is happening?

Below is:

1) the Node/SuperLogin server output showing the 30secs+ delay between the OPTIONS and the POST (OPTIONS is due to CORS, but I have the same 30secs+ delay when the POST query comes from postman, so CORS should not be the cause)

2) the Server.js source code

3) the client code.

Many thanks!

1) server output

```
>node server.js
Memory Adapter loaded
App listening on 3000
::1 - - [29/Nov/2016:21:44:42 +0000] "OPTIONS /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 204 - "http://localhost:8100/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [29/Nov/2016:21:45:19 +0000] "POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 201 27 "http://localhost:8100/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.87 Safari/537.36"
```

2) server source code (run through `node server.js`)

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');
var SuperLogin = require('superlogin');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('combined', { immmediate: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});

var config = {
  dbServer: {
    protocol: 'http://',
    host: 'localhost:5984',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'bigsecret',
    userDB: 'sl-users',
    couchAuthDB: '_users'
  },

  mailer: {
    fromEmail: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    options: {
      service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
          pass: 'mypwd'
        }
    }
  },
  userDBs: {
    defaultDBs: {
      private: ['supertest']
    }
  },
}

// Initialize SuperLogin 
var superlogin = new SuperLogin(config);

// Mount SuperLogin's routes to our app 
app.use('/auth', superlogin.router);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
console.log("App listening on " + app.get('port'));
```

3) client code

```
  var headers = $http.defaults.headers.post;
  var user = {
      "name": 'John',
      "username": 'John',
      "email": 'contact7@john.com',
      "password": 'passwd',
      "confirmPassword": 'passwd'
  };
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    url: "http://localhost:3000/auth/register",
    data: user
  };
  return $http(req)
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log("success");
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("error");
    });
```